# Не получается смещени

Tags: html, css

```css
body, h1, h2,h3,h4, p,a {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
  }

@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/NeueMachina-Regular.woff);
  font-family: "neuenormal";
  font-weight:normal;
}
  
@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/NeueMachina-Ultrabold.woff);
  font-family: "neuebold";
  font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/SpecifyPERSONAL-ExExpBlack.woff);
  font-family: "specify";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-brand1 {
  font-family: specify;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 40px;
}

.nav-link1 {
  font-family: neuebold;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar {
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
}

.holst {
  background-image: url(../img/back.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size:auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding-left: 6rem;
}

.yellow {
  color: #FDDB27;
}

.card3 {
 padding-top:100px;
 background-color: none;
}

.card3 {
  background-color: #fff0;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-top: 0;
 }

.card1 {
  background-color: none;
  background-image: url(../img/150.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
 }

 .card2 {
  background-color: none;
  padding-top:0px;
  background-image: url(../img/151.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
 }

.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.row {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.smm {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: specify;
  font-size: 65px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #00B1D2;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  line-height: 0.9;
}

.promotion {
  color: #00B1D2;
  font-size:120px;
  font-family: neuebold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 0.9;
}

.consultations{
  font-family: neuenormal;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 375px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.consultations2 {
  font-family: neuenormal;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 120px;
  padding-left: 240px;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}

img {
  float: left;
}

.about {
  font-family: neuenormal;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 70px;
  color: white;
}

.cards {
  background-color: #fff0;
  background-image: url(../img/Square\ Plastic\ 84.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.car1 {
  background-color: #fff0;
  background-image: url(../img/153.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 500px;
  background-size: 500px 500px;
}

.face {
}

  @media only screen and (max-width: 1400px){
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        padding-left: 2rem;
    }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
      .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
          padding-left: 3rem;
      }

      .nav-link1 {
        font-size: 25px;
      }

      .navbar-brand1 {
        font-size: 25px;
      }
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>teleginsmm</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/normalize.css">
</head>
<div class="holst">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark " style="background-color: none;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand1" href="#">telegin<span class="yellow">smm</span></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link1 child" href="#">кто</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link1" href="#">зачем</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link1" href="#">услуги</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link1" href="#" >контакты</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="card card1 card3">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="smm">smm</p>
            <p class="promotion">про</p>
            <p class="promotion">дви</p>
            <p class="promotion">жение</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="card card2 card3">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="consultations">Получить<br>бесплатную<br>консультацию</p>
            <p class="consultations2"><span class="white">Повышение продаж и узнаваемости бренда,<br> формирование положительного<br> имиджа с помощью популярных соц сетей</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondpage">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="card cards">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img src="assets/img/152.svg" alt="Ой, какие-то проблемки, сори" width="30" height="30">
              <p class="about">Регулярная отчетность<br>
                о проделанной работе </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="card cards">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img src="assets/img/152.svg" alt="Ой, какие-то проблемки, сори" width="30" height="30">
              <p class="about">Комплексный подход<br>
                к решению задач</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="card cards">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img src="assets/img/152.svg" alt="Ой, какие-то проблемки, сори" width="30" height="30">
              <p class="about">Гарантии роста<br>
                активной аудитории</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="card car1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img class="face" src="assets/img/face.jpg" alt="Ой, какие-то проблемки, сори" width="400" height="400">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="card car2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сместить картинку под синий цветочек, как на макете, когда смещаю падингами, картинка сжимается?

Comment: Рекомендую почитать, что такое позиционирование (относительное и абсолютное) и как оно поможет Вам в решении задачи

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/pozitsionirovanie-elementov - конкретно часть "Вложенные слои"

Comment: Все смещается, если делать вложенные слои

Answer (score -1, accepted):

У вас ссылки на картинки не работают, картинки не отображаются.
Когда создаете тему, то проверяйте, чтобы все работало.
Попробуйте задать дочерним элементам **position:absolute** и **z-index.**
И все изображения нужно поместить в 1 контейнер, чтобы они корректно позиционировались.

```css
body, h1, h2,h3,h4, p,a {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
  }

@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/NeueMachina-Regular.woff);
  font-family: "neuenormal";
  font-weight:normal;
}
  
@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/NeueMachina-Ultrabold.woff);
  font-family: "neuebold";
  font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/SpecifyPERSONAL-ExExpBlack.woff);
  font-family: "specify";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-brand1 {
  font-family: specify;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 40px;
}

.nav-link1 {
  font-family: neuebold;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar {
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
}

.holst {
  background-image: url(../img/back.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size:auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding-left: 6rem;
}

.yellow {
  color: #FDDB27;
}

.card3 {
 padding-top:100px;
 background-color: none;
}

.card3 {
  background-color: #fff0;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-top: 0;
 }

.card1 {
  background-color: none;
  background-image: url(../img/150.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
 }

 .card2 {
  background-color: none;
  padding-top:0px;
  background-image: url(../img/151.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
 }

.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.row {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.smm {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: specify;
  font-size: 65px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #00B1D2;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  line-height: 0.9;
}

.promotion {
  color: #00B1D2;
  font-size:120px;
  font-family: neuebold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 0.9;
}

.consultations{
  font-family: neuenormal;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 375px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.consultations2 {
  font-family: neuenormal;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 120px;
  padding-left: 240px;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}

img {
  float: left;
}

.about {
  font-family: neuenormal;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 70px;
  color: white;
}

.cards {
  background-color: #fff0;
  background-image: url(../img/Square\ Plastic\ 84.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.car1 {
  background-color: #fff0;
  background-image: url(../img/153.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 500px;
  background-size: 500px 500px;
}

.fisting_ass{
position:relative;
margin-left:250px;
}


.leatherface {
z-index: 2;
position:absolute;  
}

.suction{
z-index: 3;
position:absolute;  
width:150px;    
margin-left: 340px;
margin-top: -100px;
}

.dungeon_master{
z-index: 1;
position:absolute;
transform: rotate(180deg);
width:300px;
margin-left: -150px;
margin-top: 250px;
}






  @media only screen and (max-width: 1400px){
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        padding-left: 2rem;
    }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
      .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
          padding-left: 3rem;
      }

      .nav-link1 {
        font-size: 25px;
      }

      .navbar-brand1 {
        font-size: 25px;
      }
      }
```

```html
<div class="holst">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark " style="background-color: none;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand1" href="#">telegin<span class="yellow">smm</span></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link1 child" href="#">кто</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link1" href="#">зачем</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link1" href="#">услуги</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link1" href="#" >контакты</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="card card1 card3">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="smm">smm</p>
            <p class="promotion">про</p>
            <p class="promotion">дви</p>
            <p class="promotion">жение</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="card card2 card3">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="consultations">Получить<br>бесплатную<br>консультацию</p>
            <p class="consultations2"><span class="white">Повышение продаж и узнаваемости бренда,<br> формирование положительного<br> имиджа с помощью популярных соц сетей</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondpage">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="card cards">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img src="" alt="Ой, какие-то проблемки, сори" width="30" height="30">
              <p class="about">Регулярная отчетность<br>
                о проделанной работе </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="card cards">
            <div class="card-body">
             
              <p class="about">Комплексный подход<br>
                к решению задач</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="card cards">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="about">Гарантии роста<br>
                активной аудитории</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="fisting_ass">
          <div class="card car1">
            <div class="card-body">
            <img class ="dungeon_master" src="https://i.ibb.co/DCv0L8p/2.png" alt="Ой, какие-то проблемки, сори">
            <img class ="suction" src="https://i.ibb.co/ct8Rmr3/1.png" alt="Ой, какие-то проблемки, сори">
            <img class="leatherface" src="https://i.ibb.co/zrdD3NV/van.jpg" alt="Ой, какие-то проблемки, сори" width="400" height="400">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="card car2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```